# Traffic going through Wi-fi even though Ethernet IP was given

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

While doing some networking experiments with my new Raspberry 4, I ended up in the following situation:
the RPI4 was connected to my router both via Ethernet (IP: 192.168.1.230) and via Wi-Fi (IP: 192.168.1.200). I know this is a bit weird but it comes from the fact that the Wi-FI automatically connects, and I thought it couldn't hurt.
I wanted to do a test with `iperf` as follows:

```
LAPTOP(WIFI) -> (WIFI)ROUTER(ETH) -> (ETH)RPI4
```

To avoid being limited by RPI4's Wi-Fi, I thought it would be sufficient to specify 192.168.1.230 as the destination IP for the test, but with much disappointment, the speed was the same as with Wi-Fi. It was only after manually disabling the Wi-Fi on the RPI4 that I was able to finally see the transfer speed I expected (around 250 Mbps, and 1 Gbps with the Laptop also connected via cable).
Am I missing something or is this normal?